# price slider python-xpath

Tags: python, selenium

Here is the page link https://gettop.us/product-category/tablet/?min_price=490&max_price=100

I want select price range from $1000-$2000 and then click the Filter button. How can I do that in python-selenium?

I didnot try the code yet. If you someone share the code, that will much helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: You should have a go first, before asking for help here

Answer (score 0):

Well, since the url itself let you choose the min and max, here is a simple approach to your needs:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://gettop.us/product-category/tablet/?min_price=1000&max_price=2000')

filter_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#woocommerce_price_filter-9 > form > div > div.price_slider_amount > button')

if filter_button:
    filter_button.click()
```

After importing the selenium webdriver and the By package, you just need to declare the "driver", which is the browser itself, and then select the DOM element using the "By.CSS_SELECTOR".